# 403 Not authorized error while downloading starter code from bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, boilerplate

I have created a sample Java Cloudant web application using a Bluemix boilerplate.
After a successful completion, I tried to download the starter code for enhancement locally. Every time I attempted the download, I got a 403 Not authorized error page. I have a Bluemix account. Before trying this sample app, I have created 2-3 other Java web application that worked fine. I still have 125 days account validity is pending. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Can you provide a URL to that boilerplate?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using the "starter code download" from the boilerplates creation page. But when I tried to access the just created application from the dashboard, using the "start coding" option in the left pane, the download of the "starter code" successfully worked.